The condition "mass preserving maps" in the motivation of optimal transportation
I am reading Monge's formulation of the optimal transportation problem. It says that one wishes to find the a transport map $T: (X,\mu) \rightarrow (Y,\nu)$ that minimizes the transport cost $$\int_X |x-T(x)|d\mu (x).$$
Here we assume that $T$ is a mass preserving map, namely $\nu(B) = \mu(T^{-1}(B))$ for any measurable set $B$ in $Y$ (i.e. the amount of mass that ends up in any set $B$ in the target space $Y$ is exactly the amount of mass that was originally in the preimage $T^{-1}(B)$ in the source space $X$.)
My question: Why don't we define a mass preserving map as $\mu(B)= \nu(T(B))$ for any measurable set $B$ in $X$? Is there something unrealistic with this definition?

The simple answer is that measurable maps are defined using pre-images, not images. If you accept that, it's clear why your proposed definition does not make sense: $T(B)$ may not even be measurable, so you cannot compute $\nu(T(B))$.

@Semiclassical It's not an invariant measure because $\mu$ and $\nu$ are different (the case of equality is rather boring in this setting). It is however an example of a pushforward measure.

To complement MaoWao's comment on the measurability issue: i) [set theoretical reason] inverse image behaves well against set operations (unions, intersections, complements, etc.); ii) [meaning] $T^{-1}(B)$ represents in a sense the whole "basin of attraction" of the set $B$ via the transportation $T$. The direct image does not capture any of these items.

The pre-image-based definition is slightly more general than the image-based definition.
Actually, if the transport map $T$ is injective, these two definitions (using image or pre-image) are equivalent.
However, this is often not the case when $T$ is not injective. For exmaple, consider $T$ transport both the points $a_1$ and $a_2$ to the point $b$. Then, $T(a_1)=T(a_2)=b$. But it is not quite natural to define $\mu(a_1)=\mu(a_2)=\nu(b)$ since, intuitively, this does not satisfy the "transportation rule." In contrast, it is perfectly fine when using pre-image-based definition, i.e., $\mu(a_1)+\mu(a_2)=\nu(b)$.

Could you clarify what "transportation rule." is?

@Hanh Actually, I mean, if you transport some products to other places, it should satisfy the "law of conservation of mass," or, in my words, "transportation rule."

I hope this can still be useful, but I think a more meaningful explanation for that definition is given by this example.
Take, on $X=[0,2], Y=[0,1]$:
$\mu = \tfrac{1}{2}\mathbf{1}_{[0,2]}\,dx\ $ (i.e. the uniform probability measure on $[0,2]$), and
$\nu = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\,dx\ $ (i.e. the uniform probability measure on $[0,1]$).
Now, we would expect $T:X \to Y$ defined as
$$ T(x) = \cases{x \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ if } x \in[0,1] \\ x-1 \ \text{ if } x \in[1,2]} $$
to be a mass-preservng map (it maps a uniform on a segment of length 2 in a uniform on a segment of length 1). Indeed, we verify that for each measurable $B\subseteq[0,1]$, $$\mu(T^{-1}(B)) = \nu(B),$$ which makes tis one a good candidate definition. However, it is not true that for each measurable $A\subseteq[0,2]$,
$$ \mu(A)=\nu(T(A)), $$
and to see this you just need to take $A=[0,1]$.
In general, you have problems when you need a $T$ that transports mass in a way that is not injective (just as another answer pointed out).
